# Sort lists collects in apex in memory. In other words, is there a way to sort based on a Custom_Field__c in memory?

Tags: apex

Short of writing a potentially high cpu time method for 10k+ records, is there a better way to do this? Something like: `for (sObject s : sObjects) { if Count__c > Previous }`

Comment: In all fairness, its just Ids so this may be a decent solution. I can describe the requirement better. Need to combine 2 lists from separate objects then filter and resort them.

Comment: Create a wrapper class and implement comparable to do custom sorting. http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2015/10/10/comparable-sorting-objects-in-salesforce/ -

Comment: The documentation is pretty thorough here: **[Sorting Lists of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)**

Comment: You must be trying to get at something more complicated as I am sure you are aware you can simply sort in the query that obtains the records` [Select .... From .... Where XYZ In :YOURLIST Order By Count__c DESC]`. Or I am just not reading between your lines...

Comment: Yeah it has to be on a custom field. Adrian got me what I needed, I am wondering if this can be implemented on a wrapper list. Doesn't look like it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson can you sort by object through their relationship fields? for example on a parent? Doesn't show this anywhere in the docs.

Comment: The `Comparable` interface lets you sort by anything you want. You are only bound by your imagination.

Comment: Thats always been my problem lol